# variable in sed

Tags: bash, sed

how can I use a variable as a pattern finder for sed? for example:

```
sed -i '/$pc/ s/off/on/' ~/Documents/Mantenimiento
```

I know there is a $ in between the '' but there gotta be a way! please help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use double quotes instead of single quotes, or close the quotes just before the variable and reopen them just after.

```
sed -i "/$pc/ s/off/on/"
sed -i '/'$pc'/ s/off/on/'
```

This will let bash perform the variable evaluation normally.