# I can't replace strings correctly with sed on terminal

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting

Good day everyone, I followed the following [Find and Replace Inside a Text File from a Bash Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/525592/find-and-replace-inside-a-text-file-from-a-bash-command).

Now I am using the `sed` solution which seems to work if I use two predifined strings, but I want to replace the contents with something that is in a file, and not defined by me.

I have a file with the words "kung fu dog" i want it to be replace the word "dog" with the word "panda" but that word is in another file. I tried doing:

```
sed -i 's/dog/$(cat filethatcontainspanda)/g' /home/myhome
```

but the problem is that instead of having the word dog replaced with panda, I got the word "dog" replaced with "$(cat filethatcontainspanda)" so in the end instead of having "kung fu panda", I have "kung fu $(cat filethatcontainspanda)". Is there any workaround to this?

Comment: Did you try double quotes: `sed -i "s/dog/$(cat filethatcontainspanda)/g" /home/myhome`

Comment: Yup that solved it the double quotes worked fine, i tried double quotes around the first time like so sed -i 's/dog/"$(cat filethatcontainspanda)"/g' /home/myhome it didn't work, but your solution works great thanks a lot.

Comment: @user234688 Double quotes inside single quotes have no special meaning - you're still inside a string that is protected from expansion.

Comment: could also leave it out of quotes altogether `'s/dog/'$(cat filethatcontainspanda)'/g'`

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable in sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506537/variable-in-sed)

Comment: @jidder: NO, having quotes is much better, unless you really trust the input.

Comment: @anishsane `'s/dog/'"$(cat filethatcontainspanda)"'/g'` That would be okay though wouldnt it ? I just meant that all of it doesnt need to be in the same quotes. If there were no spaces quotes are not needed at all.

Comment: Could also use `$(<filethatcontainspanda)` instead of opening a new process for `cat`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes `"` instead of single `'` and `awk` instead of `cat`:

```
sed -i "s/dog/$(awk '{print $1}' filethatcontainspanda)/g" /home/myhome
```

Comment: Why Awk? The `cat` is fine if the file just contains one word.

Answer (score 0):

You must use " instead '

```
sed -i "s/dog/$(cat filethatcontainspanda)/g" /home/myhome
```