# sed in-place command not deleting from file in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bash script which checks for a string pattern in file and delete entire line i same file but somehow its not deleting the line and no throwing any error .same command from command prompt deletes from file .

```
#array has patterns
for k in "${patternarr[@]}
do
   sed -i '/$k/d' file.txt
done
```

sed version is >4

when this loop completes i want all lines matching string pattern in array to be deleted from file.txt

when i run `sed -i '/pataern/d file.txt` from command prompt then it works fine but not inside bash
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [variable in sed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506537/variable-in-sed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
sed -i '/$k/d' file.txt
```

The sed script is *singly-quoted*, which prevents shell variable expansion. It will (probably) work with

```
sed -i "/$k/d" file.txt
```

I say "probably" because what it will do depends on the contents of `$k`, which is just substituted into the sed code and interpreted as such. If `$k` contains slashes, it will break. If it comes from an untrustworthy source, you open yourself up to code injection (particularly with GNU sed, which can be made to execute shell commands).

Consider `k=^/ s/^/rm -Rf \//e; #`.

It is generally a bad idea to substitute shell variables into sed code (or any other code). A better way would be with GNU awk:

```
awk -i inplace -v pattern="$k" '!($0 ~ pattern)' file.txt
```

Or to just use `grep -v` and a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you got an unclosed double quote around `${patternarr[@]}` in your for statement.

Then your problem is that you use single quotes in the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) argument, making your shell not evaluate the `$k` within the quotes:

```
% declare -a patternarr=(foo bar fu foobar)
% for k in ${patternarr[@]}; do echo sed -i '/$k/d' file.txt; done
sed -i /$k/d file.txt
sed -i /$k/d file.txt
sed -i /$k/d file.txt
sed -i /$k/d file.txt
```

if you replace them with double quotes, here it goes:

```
% for k in ${patternarr[@]}; do echo sed -i "/$k/d" file.txt; done
sed -i /foo/d file.txt
sed -i /bar/d file.txt
sed -i /fu/d file.txt
sed -i /foobar/d file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. This is probably closer to what you really should be doing (no surrounding loop required):

```
awk -v ks="${patternarr[@]}" 'BEGIN{gsub(/ /,")|(",ks); ks="("ks")} $0 !~ ks' file.txt
```

but there may be even better approaches still (e.g. only checking 1 field instead of the whole line, or using word boundaries, or string comparison or....) if you show us some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes to interpolate shell variables inside the [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) command, like:

```
for k in ${patternarr[@]}; do
    sed -i "/$k/d" file.txt
done
```